# How to dynamically add scripts to webpage from an HTML string?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe

Say I have a string named html that has this in it:

```
<script>
    document.write("Some random stuff here");
</script>

<script src="someremotejsfile"></script>
```

I want to display this within an iframe window dynamically.

My original solution was to do:

```
document.open();
document.write(html);
document.close();
```

But this causes problems in firefox where the spinner keeps spinning as if its loading forever even though the content has already loaded.  My next attempt was to:

```
document.body.innerHTML = html;
```

This adds the scripts to the body, but that doesn't actually execute them.  So lastly I tried:

```
div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = html;
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

But this also doesn't seem to execute the scripts inside the html string.

So my question is, given a string of html, how do I dynamically add it to the page?  For instance, it can be an ad tag that has any number of scripts and other html elements in it.  I have no control over what that html string has in it.  It's a black box to me.  I just have to be able to take that long string of html and load it into the window (an iframe in this case).

Comment: My limited knowledge says that it is not possible. The closer you can't get is to eval **only** scripts(without tags) in a, e.g. string. I hope I'm wrong because this is interesting. +1

Comment: So this string called 'html' is a black box... But is it an entire webpage (including html and head elements) or is it just partial html?  Does it contain the scripts that you want to execute?  I think you're going to have to pull that 'html' string apart...

Comment: A useful site: [4 ways to dynamically load external javascript files](http://ntt.cc/2008/02/10/4-ways-to-dynamically-load-external-javascriptwith-source.html).  I refer to it occasionally.

Comment: May seem weird, but you can probably `document.write` that "black box" to the page...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

document.write works:

```
<iframe id="ifr"></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">

   var scr = decodeURIComponent("%3Ch1%3EHello%20World%3C%2Fh1%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert(%27Some%20random%20stuff%20here%27)%3B%3C%2Fscript%3E");

   document.getElementById("ifr").contentWindow.document.write(scr);
   document.getElementById("ifr").contentWindow.document.close();

</script>
```

(Never mind encoded URI string, just needed it to be able to assign code `<h1>Hello World</h1><script>alert('Some random stuff here');</script>` to a string variable inside of script tags

Comment: Document.write works perfectly for me on Chrome.  But, on firefox, document.write causes the window to seemingly load forever as in the spinner at the top of the page spins forever.  The content loads correctly, but FF is unable to determine when the content has actually loaded.  Even a simple document.write(html) in the iframe window where html = "<p>Hello World</p>" causes this to happen

Comment: Adding `document.close()` seems to solve this issue (updated my answer). I know you've tried this before, but can u try this again with the above solution?

Comment: So, if I keep the alert('something random') from your post, it works.  Firefox will spin like its loading and as soon as I exit the alert window the page is loaded.  However, if I take off the alert statement, leaving only "<h1>Hello World</h1>", Firefox never ceases to load.

Comment: Are you sure? Seems to work OK both as standalone script and here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ms5FA/ maybe cache is the issue?

Comment: Yep, this works.  There was a random script that I was unaware of that was causing FF to load forever.  Once I got rid of it, this method worked out.  Thnks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery you can use .html to load, and it will fire your script

```
$(document.body).html( $(document.body).html() + htmlToAdd );
```

If you're not using jQuery, you can eval manually your script..

```
function appendHTMLtoBody(html){
   var body = document.body;

   var scriptsLoaded = [].slice.apply(body.getElementsByTagName("script"),[0]);

   for(var i = 0; i < scriptsLoaded.length; i++){

       scriptsLoaded[i].setAttribute("data-loaded","true");

   }

   body.innerHTML += html;
   var allScripts = body.getElementsByTagName("script");
   for(var i = 0; i < allScripts.length; i++){


      if( allScripts[i].getAttribute("data-loaded") !== "true" ){

         var script = allScripts[i].innerHTML;
         eval(script);
      }
   }
}
```

i think will solve your problem.

Comment: Instead of $(document.body).html( $(document.body).html() + htmlToAdd );, you can also use the append function: $(document.body).append( htmlToAdd); or prepend, if you want to insert it to the front

Comment: This seems to work as well, although JQuery isn't an option for what I'm working on.